# How to remove background from image of a Button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a button using an image in Tkinter. I have added no background color to it, but you can see  there is square border coming. How to remove that thing? I only want the blue background color to appear in place of this.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsE7q.png)

```
br1 = Button(root, image=exitpic,command=close,border=0)
```

Comment: is your image in ```rgba``` format?

Comment: tkinter button does not support transparent background.  Default background color is used if you do not specify it.  You can set the background color of the button to the same as the window.

Comment: @acw1668 what if the background colour is a gradient or there are different colours not a solid one color, then what would be in that case?

Comment: Then you may try using `Canvas` and use `.create_image(...)` to simulate a button.